# Understanding Lists of Objects

Tags: c#, list

Was introduced to the concept of the generic List<>. Consider the following

```
        // Create an instance of the Theater class.
        this.MarcusTheater = new Theater();

        // Set the field values of the Theater.
        this.MarcusTheater.Screens = new List<Screen>();
        this.MarcusTheater.Screen1 = new Screen();

        // Set the field values for Screen1.
        this.MarcusTheater.Screen1.Lenght = 23;
        this.MarcusTheater.Screen1.Width = 50;

        // Add Screen1 to the Screen list.
        this.MarcusTheater.Screens.Add(this.MarcusTheater.Screen1);
```

From my understanding Screen1 is a temporary holder for the Screen instance. Once added to the list it becomes indexed within that list and isn't really Screen1? Since the instance of the Screen object is being stored within the Screen List, can I pull back this object in it's entirety? If so what is the best way to loop through a list<> of Screens in order to find Screen1? I know this might seem like a trivial question but I'm trying to nail down the basics. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of _references_, whether they're in a list or not.

Comment: Yep, I agree with @SLaks this is all about references

Comment: It seems odd that an object would have both a `Screens` list and a `Screen1` property, since the names suggest redundancy.

Comment: I guess what I was trying for was to create a list of Screens and then have one of those list items be Screen1 with unique characteristics. If I had Screen2, Screen3, etc all varying in size I would want to then reference just the Screen1 in this case and pass it back to whatever was requesting it.

Comment: @recursive: I assume this is part of the reason that the OP is trying to understand the concepts better.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have the Theater class. Specifically the declarations of Screens and Screen1.

Comment: @TargetofGravity: No problem, that's a common use case.  For that, you don't need `Screen1`, `Screen2`, or etc.  It is sufficient to have a list, then you can get an individual screen using `Screens[0]` or `Screens[1]`.

Comment: @TargetofGravity are you trying to create a template of all possible screens in `Screens` and then use them to set the 'physical' Screens? As in screen1 screen2 screen3?

Comment: @TargetofGravity could you please provide some feedback on the answers, so we can address better your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding Screen1 is a temporary holder for the Screen
>   instance.

Kind of. It's *is* a "holder", but it's not temporary. Even when you add `Screen1` to `ScreenList`, `Screen1` is still valid. You've just copied the **reference** to that object. Figure this:

```
    this.MarcusTheater = new Theater();
    this.MarcusTheater.Screens = new List<Screen>();
    this.MarcusTheater.Screen1 = new Screen();

    // <your stuff here>

    this.MarcusTheater.Screens.Add(this.MarcusTheater.Screen1);
    Screen1 thisIsTheSameScreen = this.MarcusTheater.Screens[0];
```

At this point, `this.MarcusTheater.Screen1` and `thisIsTheSameScreen` point to **the same object**. We're just passing its **reference** around.

So, if we did something like

```
    thisIsTheSameScreen.Lenght = 20;
```

We would be changing for everyone, *because it's the same object*.

> Once added to the list it becomes indexed within that list and isn't
>   really Screen1?

No. It's still the same, we are simply sharing the reference.

> Since the instance of the Screen object is being stored within the
>   Screen List, can I pull back this object in it's entirety?

Sure, just like I did above.

> If so what is the best way to loop through a list<> of Screens in
>   order to find Screen1?

You need a way to identify each screen, like an ID or a name. This way you can iterate that list and fetch the one you're looking for, either using Linq or a simple `foreach`.

> I know this might seem like a trivial question but I'm trying to nail
>   down the basics. Thank you in advance.

And you're perfectly correct. We all should understand the tools we're using.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you think of class-type storage locations (fields, parameters, array elements, etc.) as holding "object IDs".  The statement `someScreen.Width = 123;` doesn't change `someScreen`.  If, before that statement executed, `someScreen` identified the 24,601st object that was created since the program started, the statement will ask object #24601 to set its `Width` property to 123, and leave `someScreen` referring to object #24601.  If one says `someList.Add(someScreen)`, and `someList` identifies the 8,675,309th object, then, then object #8675309 will be asked to add "object #24601" to itself.  Note that the actual object #24601 will not be added to the list--merely its identity.

(I'm unaware of .NET providing a means by which one could determine which object was created between the 24,600th and 24,602nd objects, but if more than 24,602 objects have been created, exactly one such object must exist; during that run of the program, that object can never be anything other than the 24,601st object, nor can any other object ever be the 24,601st; if one accepts hypothetically that a particular object is the 24,601st one created, then "object #24601" may, within that hypothetical context, be used to refer to the object in question.)

Answer (score 0):

Screens is not a temporary screen, it is the one and only instance. When you add it to the list a pointer or reference to screen 1 is made. If you were to modify screen 1 via either the instance or the list, both instances would change in step.

You should have a read about references, and possibly c++ pointers and that should help you understand.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the objects are reference types and therefore both variables will point to the same object in memory, there's a dead easy way to test this. You can use the `Object.ReferencesEquals` method to determine if they reference the same object.

```
Screen screen1 = new Screen();
screen1.Length = 23;
screen1.Width = 50;

Screen screen2 = new Screen();
screen2.Length = 23;
screen2.Width = 50;

List<Screen> screens = new List<Screen>();
screens.Add(screen1);
screens.Add(screen2);

Debug.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(screen1, screens[0])); // outputs true
Debug.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(screen2, screens[1])); // outputs true
Debug.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(screen1, screen2)); // outputs false
```

Comment: `GetHashCode` is not a reliable way to test object identity.  `object.ReferenceEquals` is a better method.

Comment: It doesn't further one's understanding of references to muck it up with hashes and the like.

Comment: Hehe I was just adding an edit to say that, forgot/overlooked `ReferenceEquals`.